# In American English, what term can be used to refer to the secretary of a department?

Tags: word-usage, american-english

In American English, can both "departmental secretary" and "department secretary" be used to refer to the secretary of a particular department?

He was told to leave his papers with the *departmental/department* secretary.

She was the most hard-working *departmental/department* secretary he'd ever seen.

Comment: Both *department* and *secretary* have a huge variety of applications; please specify what you mean by each, and what your initial research have demonstrated.

Comment: In both the sentences, I'm asking about the preferred name of the position. For ex: Can we refer to the secretary of the department of English (in a college) by using the terms  "departmental secretary" and "department secretary"?

Comment: If you are talking government, like secretary of defense, etc. then its _cabinet secretary_.

Comment: Many departments don't have secretaries anymore.  Everyone does their own typing, and mail is handled by the guy pushing the mail cart.

Comment: I almost feel like "secretary" might be used more for "official in charge of a large organization" than "a person employed to aid with paperwork" these days. "Secretary of the Interior", "Secretary of State".  Also, the second definition known by younger people might be "the one who takes minutes at a meeting"....sort of a different official title.

Comment: I suggest googling "office manager" and see if that is what you want. Office Manager is a common term for the person that runs administrative things within an office that have little to do with the purpose of the organization itself (i.e. Marketing firms, Medical Practices, and Financial Firms all probably have an 'office manager"

Comment: @Tom22: in my experience, university departments don't have anybody called *"office managers"*. They don't see themselves as *"offices".* Maybe *"department managers"* or *"department adminstrators"* or *"department assistants"*.

Comment: It's been said about American government that the job titles with the greatest disparities are "Secretary of the Treasury" and "secretary to the Treasurer".  Tricky to get it just right.  Note that in the White House the "cabinet secretary" is the manager of paperwork going to and from the members of the President's cabinet; this is a high-level position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Departmental is an adjective so *departmental secretary* describes the type of secretary.  Department is a noun so *department secretary* might be a title, similar to *department manager*.  Compound nouns are common in English.

Which you would use would depend on which sense (type or title) you were trying to convey.

Comment: What is the difference between a *departmental secretary* and a *department secretary*? What does one do that the other doesn't?

Comment: A departmental secretary is a *kind* of secretary. Think of a rank in the military.  A departmental secretary may have a title such as "English department secretary".  If you only have one department then the title "Department secretary", while unimaginative, will do.

Comment: Rank may determine salary range and benefits while a title is what appears in the organization chart.

Comment: A rank in the military? You mean a departmental secretary is a kind of secretary the way rear admirals, vice admirals, and fleet admirals are all kinds of admirals? I really don't think that's what you mean, but I still don't know what you do mean.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Seargent Major is a rank. Company A's Seargent is a title. A pool secretary may be a lower rank than a departmental secretary but either may on a given day hold the title of "English department secretary".  I would ask for a promotion and a raise. :-)